# Not seeing drawer burger icon after adding drawer

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a drawer which should open a side menu to full screen. However after adding `drawer` I don't see the drawer icon at all. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: const Text("Nav", style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black
          )),
          centerTitle: true,
          flexibleSpace: Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          bottomOpacity: 0,
          elevation: 2,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: Text("Test")
          ),
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not able so see that `Icon` because you have set `automaticallyImplyLeading` to `false`, just change it to true or delete the line and your the `Icon` will appear

```
automaticallyImplyLeading: true, //even can remove this line
```

Comment: how can I move the drawer icon to the right side and change the color of it?

Comment: for that case you need to place and IconButton manually and action : [] and you have to pass a GlobalKey to scaffold then using that key you can open close drawer.

Comment: instead of `drawer: Drawer()` , you can use `endDrawer: Drawer()`.

Comment: yes @RanjitShrestha is also correct